# Rust struct impl method wants struct as argument

Tags: rust

I don't understand, what I am supposed to do here.

I have this rust struct with implementation:

```
use std::io;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct TemplateLoader {
  pub template: String,
  pub template_path: String
}

impl TemplateLoader {

  pub fn load_template_file(&self) -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    let opened_file = File::open(&self.template_path);

    let mut validated_file = match opened_file {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(e) => return Err(e),
    };

    let mut template = String::new();

    match validated_file.read_to_string(&mut template) {
        Ok(_) => Ok(template),
        Err(e) => return Err(e),
    }     
  }

  pub fn new(&self) -> Self {

    let template_path = String::from("templates/template.hbs");
    
    let item = Self { template_path, template: String::from("") }; 
 
    let _result = self.load_template_file(); 

    item
  
  }
}
```

When I call it from main like so

```
use crate::utils::template_loader::TemplateLoader;  

pub fn main() {
    let template_loader = TemplateLoader::new();
}
```

I keep getting

```
                      this function takes 1 argument but 0
                      arguments were supplied (rustc E0061)
let template_loader = TemplateLoader::new();
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- an argument of type `&TemplateLoader` is missing.
```

I don't understand that error message. Why does the compiler want an argument of type TemplateLoader for the ::new method, when there is none defined in the method signature?

All there is, is the &self argument, which is passed by Rust anyway.

Comment: A `new()` method shouldn't take in a reference to `self` since it doesn't exist yet. It looks like you need to remove that and then call `item.load_template_file` or  `Self.load_template_file(&item)`/`Self::load_template_file(&item)` (i don't remember if Rust uses `.` or `::` for this). `new` is a method of the class, not of the instances

Comment: I've fooled myself. Thanks for pointing out my mistake. If you'd like, you can post this a your answer. I'll  mark it off as a proper solution.

Comment: The question remains why you return a `Result` from `load_template_file()` but silence it in its invocation in `TemplateLoader::new()`. The caller won't know, whether the template has been successfully loaded and thus whether the struct is in an operational state.

Comment: @RichardNeumann That's just to shorten the example. The real code comprises quite a few more lines and has proper return enums for propagation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `new()` method shouldn't take in a reference to `self` since it doesn't exist yet.

It looks like you need to remove that and then call `item.load_template_file()` or `Self::load_template_file(&item)`.

`new()` is a method of the class, not of the instances

Comment: That would be . (dot) notation on the instance and :: (double colon) notation on the implementation ( class, if you will ).